# Make a Stripe Payment from a Node Back End

Tags: node.js, flutter, stripe-payments

I want to integrate Stripe Payment into my application (Flutter). This application works with a Node Back End.
I've succefully integrate Stripe into my App, but the payment is requested from the Front End (The PaymentIntent is generated from the BackEnd, but the Front is requesting Stripe's API to make the payment successful of not).

This is a big security breach and, to fix it, I want to make the user enter his card's informations in the Front, send them to the back, and make the payment (by requesting Stripe's API) from the Back End.

I've founded no solution, so this is why I'm requesting your help :)

Comment: Why do you think it's a security breach exactly? It's the way all Stripe integrations are designed and it allows for low latency handling of failures and retries(no need round trips to a backend to resubmit a payment or change the payment method), and it greatly simplifies non-card payment methods that involve inherently client-side payment authentication like redirecting to the customer's bank.

Comment: If the payment is done, we are sending product to the user (or adding tokens on his account), and the Front have to request the back to send products, or say that the payment is made.
But, if someone uncompile the app and send random values (like, he's paying for 1 item but passing 10 to the back), our company will be lost in one day ^^'

Comment: Yes, but you wouldn't have the frontend tell the backend that the payment was made and for how much. Your backend receives a webhook directly from Stripe and that's how you know the payment was made. e.g. https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=ios&ui=payment-sheet#ios-post-payment